# Magento2 vendor_name all upper case

Tags: magento2

Is it ok the vendor name being all upper case in Magento 2? e.g. VENDOR\Namespace\Some\ClassName.

Comment: Give it a try and let us know?

Comment: It works but it is ok with psr coding standards

Comment: I would guess no then since you are not supposed to capitalize your class names: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/

Comment: @JoshPennington, can you point me to where it is stated that you're not supposed to do that? From what I see, there's only this: "Class names MUST be declared in StudlyCaps" but StudlyCaps, according to my knowledge, are just any combination of uppercase and lowercase characters, with no rule that at least one needs to be lowercase.

Comment: StudlyCaps implies that the first letter of each word is capitalized, leaving the other letters lower case.

Comment: @JoshPennington where can I find this definition?

Comment: Look in the php-fig.org link above and it will say "StudyCaps". Typically the definition for the caps type is in how you type the word. In this case the first letter of each word is capitalized, so you can assume that you should write your class names to match it.

Comment: @JoshPennington typically it is as you say. However, in this case it may be different. In the link above, it's only defined that classes should be StudlyCaps, but without defining StudlyCaps notation itself. And on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studly_caps (sure, community-based but still the best source I could find on StudlyCaps) it is stated that it's just a combination of lowecase and uppercase characters with no information that at least one needs to be lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

It is allowed by PSRs, but is discouraged in Magento, even for acronyms.

In [PSR-1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) it is recommended to follow `StudlyCaps` for class names. 
In [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) the same is recommended without mentioning `StudlyCaps` term:

> Alphabetic characters in the fully qualified class name MAY be any combination of lower case and upper case.

Comment: Isn't StudlyCaps just any combination of lowercase and uppercase letters? Also, although it's true that acronyms are never all-uppercase in app/code/Magento, they are sometimes all-uppercase in directory names of vendor/magento/framework

Comment: StudlyCaps is any combination, that's true. There are DB and HTTP directories in Magento/Framework, but such naming is not recommended, all other acronyms are in UppoerCamelCase.