# Event not triggered when new product added in admin : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer

Need to generate an observer in magento2 for event when admin add new product, edit product and delete product and write that product details to file...

Having below code in `app/code/Weblizar/Helloworld/etc/adminhtml/events.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<config xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd'>
    <event name='controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after'>
        <observer name='Weblizar_Helloworld_Product_Save_After' instance='Weblizar\Helloworld\Observer\productSaveAfter' />
    </event>
</config>
```

and code in `app/code/Weblizar/Helloworld/Observer/productSaveAfter.php`

```
<?php
namespace Weblizar\Helloworld\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class productSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    /**
     * customer register event handler
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        //Do your stuff here!
        //die('Observer Is called!');

         /* @var $product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

        $data = array(
            'product' => $product,
            'value' => 333
        );
        $myfile = fopen("/file_path/Observer.txt", "w");
        fwrite($myfile, print_r($data, true));
        fclose($myfile);
    }
}
?>
```

Please guide what is not proper. When I set above code event is not generated when new product added in admin.

Many Thanx...Need more help...If i add below code in ProductSaveAfter.php

```
 namespace Weblizar\Helloworld\Observer;

 use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
 use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

  class productSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
  {   
    private $productRepository; 

    public function __construct(  
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository   
    ) {   
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;    
    }


    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        //Do your stuff here!
        //die('Observer Is called!');

         /* @var $product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $newid => $product->getId();
       /* $data = array(
           'product' => $product->getId(),
           'productname' => $product->getName(),
           'value' => 333
        );*/

        $productId=1;
        $product_details = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
        /*
            Here i want compelete product details that a admin adds by       catalog product=> new product
            and want to write in file
            How can i get product detail of single product (single record) from 
            product_details(repository object).
            In above $productId = 1 is set... so it wil get entire row(product detail)
            for id 1.
        */
        /*The $product_details value need to write in text.txt....
        General product details can be fetch like this:
         //var_dump($product_details->getName());
        //var_dump($product_details->getPrice());
        Don't know how to get country, category, description,image,video...

        */
        $myfile = fopen("test.txt", "a+");
        fwrite($myfile, print_r($data, true));
        fclose($myfile);
}
```

}

Comment: Should be events.xml (with S), was that a typo? Also did you clear cache and run `setup:upgrade` after adding these files?

Comment: yes there was typo.. made events.xml

Comment: Did all that but its not working...event not triggering..

Comment: Thanx jamil for ur help..

Comment: Pls guide with some other way to figure out...

Comment: Any luck @Nim Sha? I've posted an answer please let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works when I test it myself, however I changed one very important part:

```
-       'product' => $product,
+       'product' => $product->getId(),
```

So the entire piece is:

```
$data = array(
   'product' => $product->getId(),
   'value' => 333
);
```

The reason for this is when you try to log the entire product object, you are logging all of its children and references as well. I've found that instead of getting an error trying to do this, a lot of times you'll find the code just doesn't work at all. My **guess** is that the code times out because the object is too large to write out, and since you are using an observer here, the code in the foreground is still successful.

I would recommend not attempting to log entire objects. Use an IDE like PHPStorm or log one part of the code, as my example shows.

On another note [StudlyCaps is recommended for all class names](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90588/magento2-vendor-name-all-upper-case#answer-90592) but this isn't required.

Comment: Thankyou for ur help. It worked... U r right.. replaced that code..

Comment: Please check my edited question... This is were i need to use repository object and get product details... Thanx again.

Comment: Basically need value of all catalog=>product attributes..

Answer (score 1):

You can check original data of the product in `catalog_product_save_after`, if sku is empty/blank,then current product is new.

```
$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

if (empty($product->getOrigData('sku'))) {
 //this is the new product
```

Tested in Magento 2.4