# Can we use captials letters for vendor name

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.0

As per Magento 2 documentation can we use full capital letters for vendor name (i.e RSE). Also, can I get any Magento document for this?

Comment: this answer may assist you in your quest https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90588/magento2-vendor-name-all-upper-case

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

https://mage2gen.com/load/6cfff900-455c-4d0a-9704-6c0c129245f2?main_version=4

No there is no document as generally this is not best practice